# Xamarin Boolean Bindable Property

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to make clickable Icon which will be using for Wish List, for this I have created boolean property which will return Image.

This is my code, but it does not support onClick event, Please advise to figure out this problem.

```
  public class WishIconImg : Image, IDisposable
    {

        static FontImageSource unselected_source = new FontImageSource();
        static FontImageSource selected_source = new FontImageSource();

        public WishIconImg()
        {
            unselected_source.FontFamily = "FA-S";
            unselected_source.Glyph = "\U000f02d5";
            unselected_source.Color = Color.DarkOrange;

            selected_source.FontFamily = "FA-S";
            selected_source.Glyph = "\U000f02d1";
            selected_source.Color = Color.DarkOrange;



           OnClick += Checkbox_OnClick;

        }

        public static BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(IsChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(WishIconImg), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: IsCheckedChanged);

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void IsCheckedChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {

            var cb = (WishIconImg)bindable;
            if (cb == null)
                return;

            if ((bool)newValue)
            {
                cb.Source = selected_source;
            }
            else
            {
                cb.Source=unselected_source ;
            }



        }

       void Checkbox_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsChecked = !IsChecked;

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            OnClick -= Checkbox_OnClick;
        }



    }
}
```

Xaml

```
 <controls:WishIconImg   x:Name="HeartChk" IsChecked="{Binding AddWish, Mode=TwoWay}" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35"  HorizontalOptions="End"/>
```

Even I have tried with Label property but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you post xaml code for UI as well? I got a better solution for you, i will be editing your UI with better Solution if you only wants to add OnClick event on it

Comment: Xaml is added, I am just calling this control in xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the class like following

```
public WishIconImg()
        {
            unselected_source.FontFamily = "FA-S";
            unselected_source.Glyph = "\U000f02d5";
            unselected_source.Color = Color.DarkOrange;

            selected_source.FontFamily = "FA-S";
            selected_source.Glyph = "\U000f02d1";
            selected_source.Color = Color.DarkOrange;

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
                // handle the tap

                IsChecked = !IsChecked;

            };
            this.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);



        }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, the problem is gone now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy coding  .You could also use Command instead of  Event if you need to handle logic in ViewModel . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap#using-icommand .

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `TapGestureRecognizer` for an click event

Do something like this

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35"  HorizontalOptions="End">
    <controls:WishIconImg   x:Name="HeartChk" IsChecked="{Binding AddWish, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Checkbox_OnClick}" /> 
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

In your ViewModel Bind the command for it

```
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand Checkbox_OnClick => new Xamarin.Forms.Command(Checkbox_OnClickTapped);
```

> Checkbox_OnClickTapped will be your method called when your view will be clicked

Comment: what package you import for them?

Comment: If I change the code as per your example, TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Checkbox_OnClick}" />  is showing error,

Comment: Should i create Checkbox_OnClick in control or in ViewModel ?

Comment: in view model, but if your problem is already solved, you can try it for future purpose...to add click on any layout